# numpy percentile function outputs wrong values with nearest interpolation method

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, percentile

The simplest example on wiki:
[Worked examples of the nearest-rank method sample 1:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)
When compute 5th, 30th, 40th, 50th, 100th percentile for [15, 20, 35, 40, 50],
according to the wiki page, with the nearest interpolation method, the ordinal rank should always be the ceiling when the rank computed within the range of the list is not a integer.
So specifically, when compute 40th percentile like this:
40/100*5=2, the result should be 20, like what's been said on the wiki page:
[image]

but when using numpy's percentile function:

```
p = 40
r = numpy.percentile([15, 20, 35, 40, 50], p, interpolation=nearest)    
print(r)
```

r is 35, that means the ordinal rank was computed wrongly!
I looked into numpy's percentile source code, I found that

[image]

I don't know why the indice in the source code be computed as around(p/100 * (Nx-1)).astype(intp), and be use directly as the index of the list.

So my question is, is it a bug?

Comment: "40th percentile" means that 40% of the values are below the value.  With 5 values, that means there are 2 values below, which means 35.  That IS ordinal 2, assuming you start counting from 0.

Comment: I mean the explanation from wiki page of the nearest interpolation method give different answer to the same example comparing to numpy's percentile function, there should be one that's is wrong, or I misunderstood anything?

Comment: They are using a different definition of "percentile".  They are using "less than or equal to", whereas the definition I'm familiar with is "strictly less than", which is why you never see "100th percentile".  `numpy` is delivering the "strictly less than" number.

Comment: I guess it's a bug? because numpy's code: around(p/100 * (Nx-1)) not always equals to around(p/100*Nx)-1, I believe the latter is the logic when puts a series of numbers in a list which's index starts from zero. If adopt the latter one must be careful in case p and Nx are both very small, then around(p/100*Nx) is less than 1, and the index will be -1. Ugly conditional code should do the tricks, though lack elegancy.

Comment: If your sample size is small, then "percentile" is not a particular useful metric to use.  If you use "higher" interpolation, aren't the results exactly what the article suggest?  More importantly, what do YOU need for YOUR results?  There is no one right answer here.

Comment: I finally give up searching for a precise form for computing percentile of small samples. It's useless in statistics. Now I decide to accept what the tool I use behaves, Thank you for your advice and discussion Mr. Roberts!